# Como incluir os artefatos dos testes unitários numa simples aplicação Java?

Tags: java, junit

Esse é meu projeto no meu repositório;

[PROJETO](https://github.com/wladyband/testGamer)

Observe o arquivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.wladimir</groupId>
    <artifactId>GamerGourmet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.22</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-gui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>gui</headerType>
                            <outfile>target/GamerGourmet.exe</outfile>
                            <jar>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</jar>

                            <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                            <errTitle>Error in launch4j plugin</errTitle>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>com.test.wladimir.gamergourmet.main.GamerGourmet</mainClass>
                            </classPath>
                            <jre>
                                <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
                                <initialHeapSize>512</initialHeapSize>
                                <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                            </jre>
                            <versionInfo>
                                <fileVersion>0.0.0.1</fileVersion>
                                <txtFileVersion>0.0.0.1</txtFileVersion>
                                <fileDescription>des</fileDescription>
                                <copyright>Copyright (c) 2018 </copyright>
                                <companyName>comp</companyName>
                                <productVersion>0.0.0.1</productVersion>
                                <txtProductVersion>${project.version}</txtProductVersion>
                                <productName>GamerGourmet</productName>
                                <internalName>GamerGourmet</internalName>
                                <originalFilename>GamerGourmet.exe</originalFilename>
                            </versionInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>GamerGourmet</name>
</project>
```

Como faço para incluir o pacote do Junit nesse arquivo pom.xml?

Esse é o pacote do Junit;

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Estou utilizando o **NetBeans**

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa adicionar a tag `dependencies` no seu pom, após ou antes da tag `build`:

```
[...]
</build>
<name>GamerGourmet</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Essa tag é responsável por gerenciar as dependências do seu projeto. Para cada nova dependência, basta adicioná-la dentro da tag `dependencies`.